# Disable search result preview

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, search-results, preview

**Hey**

As the title indicates, I wanna know who to disable the search preview (that on search result web part)

Because on the onload of the SharePoint page, i have a list who contains my folder .

It appeared when i added a query rules in the panel "Build Query" (I added a property filter)

Just look my picture, i want the folder disappear  and just have my search box on the onload

I know we can disable ALL preview feature with sharepoint admin center but that not what i'm looking for i just want fot this page.

[image]

**Thanks for your help.**

Answer (score 0):

I looked at html code and noted that if your search results web part has id `WebPartWPQ2` then when you search something it changes the `style` attribute of it's second `div` with search results.

So you can write JS code:

```
window.onload=function(){
  document.getElementById("WebPartWPQ2").childNodes[1].style.display="none";
}
```

This `none` value would be replaced by searching function.

**UPD**. Ah, it's for **on-premise SP** where I tested it.

Comment: that doesn't work, nothing happens :c